# Getting LNK1104: cannot open file "libssl.obj"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, linker, openssl

After many internet searches i am posting this question.
  I am trying to compile existing c++ code which involves openssl libraries.
  I was able to include openssl header files successfully in visual studio 2013. And also i am running the application on Windows 8.1 platform.
  During compilation, I am facing the below error:

```
LNK1104: cannot open file "libssl.obj"
```

I need to add libssl , libcrypto and ws2_32 in the linker properties. Somehow it is throwing the above error even though i include the libssl.a and libcrypto.a as well as ssleay32.lib and libeay32.lib !!!!!!!!!!

[Note] The same codebase compiles fine in MinGW by giving

```
g++ ***source-files***** -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -lws2_32
```

Thanks for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you don't have libssl.obj compiled. Also make sure libssl.lib is in your PATH environment.

Comment: So, it is necessary to compile it using VS2013 runtime. And you will get libssl.lib on Windows.

Comment: Probably, [this resource](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) would be somewhat helpful to you. However, I don't see there library built using VS2013. Thus, if you will use ssl binary compiled with another runtime you could end up with runtime compatibility problems. So, as drecherjm said "you need to build it yourself".